# Just a quick check on this inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $A\geqslant B$, $C\geqslant D$, $A \geqslant C$ and all of them are non negative.

Is it true that $A-C\geqslant B-D$?

Edited. I'm interested in $\geqslant$ not $>$

Comment: Have you tried with a few examples, see whether it _ought_ to hold?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm interested in $>=$

Comment: I still stand by my comment. Have you tried with a few examples, seen whether it _ought_ to hold?

Comment: Oh right, I know where I went wrong Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's wrong.

Try $(A,C,B,D)=(5,4,3,1)$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was interested in $\geqslant$

Comment: @user164144 It doesn't matter. $1>2$ and $1\geq 2$ (which is what you get with this example) are equally false.

Comment: @user164144 We have $5-4\geq3-1$. I think it's wrong.

Comment: Yep, I saw what I was doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @user164144 You are welcome!